# Styling a box-shadowed element with cutoff

Tags: html, css

We're trying to create an HTML page that consists of masonry-style floated elements that contain a picture and title. The elements have a shadow and the page has a slight gradient background. Targets that have already been visited have a folded corner.

[image: Example of what we're trying to achieve]

The folded corner causes a couple of problems:

1) How can we make the element's box-shadow end before the folded corner on the right and bottom sides? Will we have to do the shadows the pre-CSS3 way with `div`s containing semi-transparent gradients?

2) How to do the folded corner itself? We can't just impose an image on the right bottom corner on top of the white background, because the page's background gradient must show through.

Comment: This is not possible with `box-shadow` However, the new shadow css filter will do the trick. http://www.tagindex.net/css/filter/dropshadow.html

Comment: @TorstenWalter: But hasn't the shadow filter been around since IE 5.5? The problem with it is that it only works on IE and only support solid color shadows.

Comment: Oh, there seems to be a similarly named *new* filter property. We'll probably have to wait for at least a couple of years before using it, since the support seems to be currently limited to Webkit browsers. Your link referred to the old IE-only version, here's a link to the newer one: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html

Comment: Regarding question 2) couldn't you just use a CSS sprite? A png with transparency for the lower div (a solid white rectangle and a cut off rectangle with coloured triangle in one image)?

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja Thanks for the link. I knew that the property was there and worked (used it in a workshop) but obviously found the wrong reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, I've thought of four ways of doing this:

**Method 1**: The idea behind this one is to use two pseudo-elements on the `.box` to get the corner and then two pseudo-elements on the `.box-text` to get the shadows in the corners right - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3246830). The biggest problem with this one is that it is... well, ugly.

HTML structure:

```
<div class="box">
    <header></header>
    <div class="box-text">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.box {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 13px #000;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}
.box:before, .box:after, .box-text:before, .box-text:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
}
.box:before {
    bottom: -25px;
    right: -25px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.box:after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 2px #777;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 38%, #333 50%, #faf0f0 50%);
}
.box-text:before {
    bottom: 32px;
    right: -15px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 18px;
    background: radial-gradient(top left, #333 0%, transparent 40%);
}
.box-text:after {
    bottom: -15px;
    right: 32px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 15px;
    background: radial-gradient(top left, #333 0%, transparent 40%);
}
```

---

**Method 2**: combine shadows in a nicer manner using a skewed pseudo-element for that particular corner (I would have shadows on the pseudo-element) - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3246978)

I think this one looks nicer and also has the advantage of working in IE9 as well (the previous one didn't, since it made use of CSS gradients).

The HTML would be exactly the same and the CSS would become:

```
.box {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #777;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}
.box:before, .box:after, .box-text:before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    content: '';
}
.box:before {
    bottom: -38px;
    right: -38px;
    width: 71px;
    height: 71px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 1;
    background: #ccc;
}
.box:after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 23px #f9f0f0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #777;
    z-index: 4;
}
.box-text:before {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 22px;
    width: 47px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 1px #777;
    transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
```

---

**Method 3**: I got an idea from the previous method - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3247255). I think the previous one looks slightly nicer though...

CSS that has changed:

```
.box:before {
    bottom: -24px;
    right: -7px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 0 3px 1px #999;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 1;
    background: #ccc;
}
.box:after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 23px #f9f0f0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #777;
    z-index: 4;
}
.box-text:before {
    bottom: -27px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 70px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: #ccc;
}
```

**Method 4**: Uses just 2 pseudo-elements, both on the box - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3247461)

```
.box:before, .box:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    content: '';
}
.box:before {
    right: -8px;
    bottom: 22px;
    width: 65px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px #777, 0 25px 0 25px #ccc;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.box:after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 23px #f9f0f0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #777;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great examples! Unfortunately we had to ditch the folded corners because modern browsers impose very strict limitations to styling the `:visited` pseudoselector due to possible privacy issues. I'll accept this helpful answer nevertheless.